# First not none response when iterating over list of functions

Tags: python, lambda

I've got a list of functions, each of which can return `None` or a valid value. I want to take the result of the first `not None` response:

```
funcs = (lambda: None, lambda: None, lambda: True)
result = next((f() for f in funcs if f()), None)  # result = True
```

This works, but I don't like that I've had to execute the function twice to perform the test and generate the result. Is there any way to only execute `f()` once and maintain the solution?

PS. I know I can do this in a `for` or traditional loop (that's how the code currently is), I'm looking for a nice one liner :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to remove any falsey results (including `None`) as you iterate:

```
try:
    # Forward compatibility for Python 2
    from future_builtins import filter
except ImportError:
    pass

result = next(filter(None, (f() for f in funcs)), None)
```

To make sure you use the *iterator* version of `filter()` in Python 2 as well I used the [`filter` function from the `future_builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.filter).

Just a demo to show that this won't execute more functions than needed:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from future_builtins import filter
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> funcs = (lambda: None, lambda: None, lambda: True, lambda: 1/0)  # last one throws an exception!
>>> next(filter(None, (f() for f in funcs)), None)
True
```

Comment: Yes but that'll go through all the values `funcs`, this example is trivial but I'm using `next()` so it exits straight away because in my actual code each func is doing database multiple calls.

Comment: @AlexLatchford: no, it won't. The Python 3 version of `filter` iterates lazily.

Comment: Ah awesome, so if I use regular python 2.x version it will iterate though all values first right? (Just to make sure my logic of v2 filter is correct)

Comment: @AlexLatchford: yes, the Python 2 built-in `filter()` function would return a list, having consumed the whole input iterator.

Comment: Fantastic, answer will be accepted in 7 mins when the timer expires!

Comment: I suppose another option is: `next((b for f in funcs for b in [f()] if b), None)`

Comment: Using `None` as the first argument to `filter` will filter all non-`True` items, not just `None` items.

Comment: @chepner: which is exactly what the OP was doing, using `if f()`. But I see my answer was misleading in that regard, updated.

Comment: @user1501961: I was thinking of that option, as well as `next((res for res in (f() for f in funcs) if res), None)`, first, but  `filter()`  really is preferable here.

Comment: That conflicts with "I want to take the result of the first not None response", though. That is, shouldn't it return `False` with `funcs = (lambda: None, lambda: False, lambda: True, lambda: 1/0)`?